# How to highlight top note while playing triads / intervals

Tags: piano, technique, beginner, chopin

I am trying to learn funeral march op 35 by Chopin and the initial motive is played using some intervals in which the top note should be the melody thus should be louder then the other notes you are playing with right hand. I noticed that technique also in other songs but never really paid attention to figuring things out clearly.

For example I want to play D-F# traid but I want to control the volume of each note so F# sounds bright and D is in the background.

I am a beginner and wondering if this is advanced technique and should skip it for now? How to I learn to control the volume of each note in triads / intervals? Is there any progression of exercises that would lead me to my goal? What cues should I think about?

Comment: To help answer how to balance individual fingers so that the top notes are more prominent, are you currently able to play such that one hand is louder than the other? For example, can you play a right-hand melody louder than its left-hand accompaniment?

Comment: @Aaron yes with that I am fairly comfortable, I think this is not perfect but good enough

Comment: Have you worked on five finger/finger independence exercises? That's beginner stuff, but in part it's about balance of strength between the fingers, which is essentially what your issue is about.

Comment: Are you playing an "easy" arrangement of this piece? I'm a little confused about you saying you're a beginner, but working on this piece which isn't really beginner material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s advanced-ish, or at least intermediate. There is an exercise that helps with controlling the volume of each note:

- Rest your fingers on the keys of a chord like you’re going to play it
- While keeping all the fingers on the keys of the chord, lift a single finger and bring it down to play the note of the chord that the finger is for
- Repeat the above 2-5 five times, then move on the the next note of the chord and its corresponding finger
- Do this exercise for several chords in the progression each day
- Start to work on playing the chords with one note being loudest - you should be able to learn to put a little more into a specific finger to make that note louder

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what I was looking for in regards of answer.

Comment: @krajew4 if you like this answer you should upvote it! And possibly even accept it later on…

Comment: @krajew4 Be *very* careful about lifting your fingers. This is one of the most common causes of piano-playing injury. My suggestion is to modify the exercise by omitting the lift and just playing each note by allowing the corresponding fingertip to support some of your arm weight.

Comment: I *think* I get more volume from say, pinky, by rotating my forearm as I play a note with it. Not so much lifting it. And other fingers - I use wrist with that particular finger already lower, so it contacts the key sooner - but with impetus from the wrist rather than the finger itself.

Comment: @Tim This exercise isn’t about the technique, it’s about building awareness of the chord voicing. When actually playing the chord, you don’t lift one finger higher than the others.